# Enable or Disable Button Based On TextBox.Text Text Changes

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am creating a web application for my company. My application has a button and a textbox.

What I want to do is entering some value into the textbox and then when i click the button the application will process the value based on the input in the textbox.

Now here is the tricky part.

After the button is clicked once and the text in textbox remains, the button shall disappear.

However if there is modification in the textbox.text, the button shall reappear.

But if the textbox.tex somehow return to original value, the button shall disappear again.

Please its quite urgent, I have tried my best to do it already, yet so far unsuccessful. I also did a lot of research in Google, but so far none of my findings suit my case.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: if you'll include the code samples the answer may be far more useful

Comment: original value? is that the value once the button has been pressed?

Comment: original value of the textbox is empty, user must key in some text first. when button pressed, the value of textbox unchanged, instead it will hide the button itself, the button only showed again upon the changing in the textbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got it here http://jsfiddle.net/ywe9G/

```
var ori = '';
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').hide();
    $('input').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val() != ori){
                $('button').show();
        }else{
            $('button').hide();
        }
    });
    $('button').click(function(){
        ori  = $('input').val();
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    private string oldTextboxValue = "";
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != oldTextboxValue)
        {
            button1.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            button1.Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oldTextboxValue = textBox1.Text;
        button1.Visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to disable button you can do this-

```
var oldvalue="";
$('#buttonid').click(function(){
//your code
oldvalue = $("#textBox").text();
this.hide();
}

$("#textBoxId").keypress(function(){
if(this.value!=oldvalue){
this.show();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/t2vNJ/3/)

**HTML**

```
<textarea id='mytext' rows='4' cols='20'></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" id='my_button' value="click">
<input type="hidden" id="my_hidden">
```

**jQuery**

```
var clicked=false;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_button").click(function(){
        $("#my_hidden").val($("#mytext").val());
        $(this).hide();
        clicked=true;
    });

    $("#mytext").keyup(function(){
       if(clicked==true && $(this).val()==$("#my_hidden").val()) {
           $("#my_button").hide();
       }else if(clicked==true){
           $("#my_button").show();
       }
    });

});
```

You can similarly enable/disable button instead of show/hide

Comment: hey thank's do you have any idea on how this work together with asp.net?

Comment: nope idont have any idea of .net i am a java guy but why do you need that?

Comment: because i am basically developing the application using .NET and C#. and I don't use the <input> or <button> tags, instead i used <asp:button> and <asp:textbox>

Comment: <asp:button> and <asp:textbox> tags end up in <button> <input> tags on the browser.

Comment: Actually, you're fiddle is behaving opposite to the requirement. Is right @MrHypercrite?

Comment: @ Moe Sweet: oh yes. I read the question wrongly :). Now updated the fiddle and the answer.Tnx